# Show error message when you click checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, messages

I want to be able to show a message when my user clicks on the "checkout" button. Because I need to check if the final cart amount isn't lower then 30€.

So I figured it'll be best to show the message when the user clicks the checkout button.

I created this .xml, but don't know if that's the event to use "sales"

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Curiosidade_CompraInicial>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Curiosidade_CompraInicial>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <curiosidade_comprainicial>
            <class>Curiosidade_CompraInicial_Model</class>
        </curiosidade_comprainicial>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <curiosidade_comprainicial>
            <class>Curiosidade_CompraInicial_Helper</class>
        </curiosidade_comprainicial>
    </helpers>      
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_save_before> 
            <observers>
                <curiosidade_comprainicial_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
                    <class>curiosidade_comprainicial/observer</class>
                    <method>enforceCompraInicialLimit</method>
                </curiosidade_limitedinheiro_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
<default>
    <sales>
        <curiosidade_comprainicial>
            <active>1</active>
            <compra_inicial_montante>1500</compra_inicial_montante>
            <compra_inicial_montante_msg><![CDATA[Não pode fazer uma compra acima de %s.]]></compra_inicial_montante_msg>
        </curiosidade_comprainicial>
    </sales>
</default>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set minimum order from admin. Login into your admin account, go to `system--> configuration -->sales(from left side bar) --> Minimum order amount`. Enter your minimum order amount here, save it..That's it..!

**Update:**
  So you want set min order amount for a customer's first order only, Here we go..!
For that you would need to override following  event observer

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler
```

so for that,
create a module  and your `Mypackage/Minorder/etc/config.xml` file would be,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mypackage_Minorder>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mypackage_Minorder>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <minorder>
        <class>Mypackage_Minorder_Helper</class>
      </minorder>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <minorder>
        <class>Mypackage_Minorder_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>minorder_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </minorder>
    </models>
    <events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>minorder/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>minorderAction</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And `Mypackage/Minorder/Model/Observer.php`,

```
<?php
class Mypackage_Minorder_Model_Observer
{

   public function minorderAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

        /* Get the customer data */
         $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();


        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

         if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && (!$orders->getSize()))
          { 
         // has never placed an order 

               $subtotal = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

                if($subtotal <= '4000') {

                    echo "Minimum order amount is Rs.4000";
                    exit;
                }
                else {

                    return true;

                    }

                exit;
}

}


            }

}
```

And `Mypackage/Minorder/Model/Helper.php`,

```
<?php
class Mypackage_Minorder_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**update:2**

And `app/etc/Mypackage_Minorder.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mypackage_Minorder>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mypackage_Minorder>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I have checked this, this is working fine.Here I set min order amount is 4000, you can change it as your wish.. If you have any doubt, let me know..! cheers ..!

Comment: But I just want for the first purchase, not always

Comment: For that you should hardcoded your application..

Comment: I'm trying to build an extension

Comment: I ll help you for that ..

Comment: so your requirement is, you want to set min order amount for a customer's first order only, right ..?

Comment: Yes that's the problem I need to solve

Comment: I have update my answer..Checkout..

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll edit it to use this to make it in trimesters codepaste.net/5ound9

Comment: Do I need to create a .xml inside modules folder ?

Comment: yes..you need to create Mypackage_Minorder.xml file under app/etc/modules folder. I thought you were aware of magento modules ..I have updated my ans..

Comment: I'm, but I'm still very newbie. Can you help one another one ? Can you please join ? chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14330/discussion-between-user3497472-and-elavarasan?